# GWT access denied to save file in any folder

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload

I'm uploading a file to my GWT application by using this [tutorial](http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/fileupload_with_gwt). This file is uploaded via a servlet and each time I wish to save the file or to read it with getInputStream I get the message:

**> access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\NESPRE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\poifiles" "write")**

How can I ensure the file can be read? thanks!

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
...
 List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(req);
 if (item.isFormField()) 
         continue;

String fileName = item.getName();
if (fileName != null) {
   fileName = FilenameUtils. getName(fileName);
}

File uploadedFile = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, fileName);
if (uploadedFile.createNewFile())  //throw the exception here

}
```

Comment: This is a folder on your hard drive. Did you check the permissions for this folder?

Comment: thanks @Andrei Volgin  - It looks like any folder doesn't allow to 'write' (though it has a write permission). My objective is just to read the file but I need to 'save' it somewhere.

Comment: It matters who has the "write" permission. Your JVM may not have this right.